# retrieving inline-element position and dimensions relative to parent's lines of text

Tags: javascript, html, css, inline

I would like to ask if it is possible to get the relative position (x,y) of the beginning and the end of an inline element relative to its parent, taking into account the height too. Let's consider the case an inline element starts at a certain line of the parent element, p for example, and ends at next line; let's say it is taller. I would like to be able to understand which lines it has been displayed in and their height.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help [jquery position](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

and for the height you could use the "height()" to get the computed height

Comment: I wonder if height() accounts for the total height, that is the "multi-line" height?

Comment: sorry for the late, late, late response... height(), returns the computed height of the element. if you have a fixed height defined in css or inline it will reeturn that value if it has auto or not defined it will return the computed